# Pager smaller and without borderlines

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, webforms

I am starting to code in webforms just for a while, and I am quite newy using its differents elements. Now I coded a gridview, everything is ok, but I am having troubles with de footer.

I can´t get a footer with a pager inside smaller than the all row. Please, see image below:

[image]

I would like to get like two small squares (or more if pager need it) in the right of the screen without borderlines.

It is strange, I set this configuration on the definition of the gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView ...PagerStyle-BorderStyle="None" PagerStyle-Height="200" PagerStyle-Width="400">
```

Seting a specific class and assign it to the footer, in gridview defintion:

```
 <asp:GridView ... PagerStyle-CssClass="pagerElias" >

..pagerElias{
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:right;
    border-style:hidden;
}
```

Even trying to setting them in another row (first by then by property, then setting a class):

```
<PagerStyle CssClass="pagerElias"/>

.pagerElias{
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:right;
    border-style:hidden;
}
```

Farest I got is the image´s situation.

Please, give a clue about what I am doing wrong...

Thanks mates

Comment: A pager is a nested table inside the GridView. So you might need to use `.pagerElias table {` or `.pagerElias td {`. Take a look at the source html and see what is being generated.

Comment: It works... Thanks... @VDWWD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @VDWWD comment, I defined a class in my css kind of:

```
.pagerElias td {
        height:200px;
        width:400px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:right;
        border-style:hidden;
}
```

And I use this class in my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ... PagerStyle-CssClass="pagerElias" >
```

In that way, I am setting the td inside the gridview that has pagerElias´s class.

Thanks